MacBook Pro: can't type login password with wireless USB keyboard (only built-in kbd works)
I have a 2021 MacBook Pro with Sonoma 14.5.
When I boot or wake from hibernation*, my wireless USB keyboard doesn't work when I'm trying to type my password.
So I need to walk around my desk (since my MacBook needs to face the other way because of the ports that I need to use) and go type on the built-in keyboard, which is annoying since I much prefer using my external keyboard at my standing desk.
How can I change whatever setting is causing this behavior?
If there is some concept of USB peripherals needing to be approved, I want to permanently grant my USB keyboard permission to be used (even for typing the login password, even after having been unplugged and replugged).
My previous MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019) with macOS Monterey 12.4 never had this problem with this USB keyboard.
*I don't use regular "Sleep". I ran sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 25.
Update 1:
Thanks to the comment from Linc D., I see:

I will change to "Always" and report back if that setting fixed my problem. I bet it will.
Update 2:
The way I wake my Mac is open the lid and tap the Space bar.

in Hiberbate, only a power button on USB keyboards will wake the laptop. that may have been different before?

@cmason The computer is awake, and I can see the password input box on my external display. But my wireless USB keyboard does not work until after login.

In System Settings > Security and Privacy > Security, if "Ask for new accessories" is selected, deselect it. Any change?

Please, specify in your OQ how you boot or wake from hibernation your Mac.

@dan Updated. The way I wake my Mac is open the lid and tap the Space bar. Thanks.

@LincD. I updated my question based on your suggestion. I bet you are right! I have changed the setting to "Always", and it seems to be behaving how I hoped so far.  Feel free to write an answer if you'd like, and I'll accept it. Thanks so much for helping me with this! ❤️

Before posting an answer, I would like to know whether the keyboard still works when you revert that setting. As it is, the security of the machine is weakened.

@LincD. Yes, I just tried reverting the setting, and on the next wake, I needed to use the built-in keyboard to log in and approve the USB accessories. And now the external keyboard works. Re: "the security of the machine is weakened", probably not much, right? I think it's only weaker if someone has physical access to plug in USB accessories. I'm confident in my local (physical proximity) security. And I don't think this makes me more vulnerable to remote attacks. Thanks.

On MacBooks, but not desktop Macs, there is a menu
System Settings > Security and Privacy > Security > Allow accessories to connect
For third-party USB keyboards, if this setting is set to Ask for New Accessories or Ask Every Time, the USB keyboard can't be used to log in by default. Select Ask for New Accessories, disconnect the USB keyboard, log in with the built-in keyboard, and then connect the USB keyboard again. A dialog will prompt you to approve the accessory.
Be aware, though, that in general, USB devices can't be identified uniquely. They can only be identified by vendor and product ID, which are the same for all devices with the same characteristics. A malicious USB device, such as a hardware keylogger, could have the same identifiers as a legitimate one. So you can't just assume that the keyboard you approved is actually the same one that is connected later. Use caution when connecting unknown USB devices.

For me, this wasn't the answer though. "Ask for New Accessories" was already the setting that I had when I asked the question. I changed to "Always", which then solved it for me. I would have guessed that "Ask for New Accessories" would suffice since I'm using the same accessories each time (so I don't know why they'd be considered new).

I know this isn't what you did, but it would have worked either way. I think the answer as posted is better, because "Always" is really not something I want to encourage.

This morning, with my setting still on Ask for New Accessories, my Macbook let me log in by typing on my external keyboard. So I'm accepting this answer. Thanks! P.S. Weirdly, although my mouse worked too (which uses the same wireless USB adapter since it came as a set with the keyboard), the mouse wheel didn't work until toggling my USB switch off and on. But that feels like a potentially unrelated issue.

Note to self: I just changed this setting to Automatically When Unlocked, which I don't remember seeing as an option before. I'm tired of needing to walk around and use the built-in keyboard when the Macbook incorrectly thinks my external keyboard is a new accessory (after pressing the button on my USB switch to reconnect this external keyboard to the Macbook).

Note to self: I just changed this setting to Always because I'm so tired of having to walk around my desk to go type in the password. Apple sucks. This feature just doesn't work. Hopefully Always will be enough.
